# ssh stuck when downloading files from s3

Tags: bash, ssh, amazon-s3

My current set up:

Machine A -> log into Machine B -> download files from s3

I run following command from A:

For each file

```
 ssh user@MachineB s3cmd get --skip-existing --no-progress $s3_path $path_temp
```

However the above command gets stuck at ssh. I could not find any `s3 get` process running on Machine B and all files were not copied. ssh was stuck for 1-2 weeks.

What is the reason for this behavior and what can I do to avoid it?

Edit: Initially the command was written in two separate lines. Rectified it

Answer (score 0):

I think your script stops after ssh command, because ssh needs password or key.

You should install sshpass (apt-get install sshpass) and try this out:

```
sshpass -p destinationPassword ssh user@MachineB "s3cmd get --skip-existing --no-progress ${s3_path} ${path_temp}"
```

Comment: This is not the problem. Above command succeeds many times. Though there are 3-4 instances when it is stuck

Comment: Then you can write out the exit code with $? (it returns with the last command's exit code) and the command output with this after the command --> 2>&1 | tee $mysqlLogfile > /dev/null

Comment: Exit code is returned when program has finished it's execution/is killed in some way. In this case I guess ssh is not able to detect that program has been killed due to some reason

Comment: Btw why didn't run the script in the remote machine (Machine B)?